# Behavior of the solutions to a system of linear differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x(t)=(x_1(t),\cdots,x_n(t)):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable and satisfy:
$$x'(t)=Ax(t)$$
where $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is a real matrix.
I have known that if the real part of all eigenvalues of $A$ are strictly negative, then $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}x(t)=0$. 
However, if we assume $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}x(t)=0$ and $x_1(t),\cdots,x_n(t)$ are linearly independent, what can we say about the matrix $A$?
I guess the real part of all eigenvalues of $A$ should be strictly negative, but I cannot deal with the case that the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is purely imaginary number. In this case, $x_i(t)$ may be like this:
$$c_1\sin \mu_1t+c_2\sin\mu_2t+\cdots+c_2\sin\mu_kt$$
where $\mu_k>0$
I guess this is impossible since $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}x(t)=0$, but I don't know how to prove it.
By the way, the original problem is that if all $a_{ij}\geqslant0$ and $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}x(t)=0$, prove that $x_1(t),\cdots ,x_n(t)$ cannot be linearly independent.
The solution is that use Perron's theorem to find a non-negative eigenvalue $\lambda$ and its eigenvector $(\alpha_1,\cdots ,\alpha_n)$. Let $y(t)=\alpha_1x_1(t)+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n(t)$ and we will find that $y'=\lambda y$ and $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow +\infty}y(t)=0$, so $y(t)\equiv0$, which means $x_1(t),\cdots,x_n(t)$ are linearly dependent.